# why we can't use multiple this() in Constructor Overloading?

Tags: java, constructor, this, constructor-overloading

i'm newbie in this world currently i'm learning java and i wanna to know why i can't use multiple this() in a constructor someone can tell me why please?

```
public class Student {
        private String name;
        private int age;
        public Student(String name) {
            System.out.println("Name of Student : " + name);

        }

        public Student(int age)
        {
            System.out.println("Age of student = " + age);

        }

      public Student()
        {
         this("Alex");
         this(22); //Error in this line:Call to 'this()' must be first statement in constructor body
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Student student=new Student();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the language only allows one of these. It is part of the creation of the object. Think of it this way: multiple `this(..)` calls would create multiple instances within the execution of a constructor. You can combine both cases into a `Student(String name, int age) constructor though and then call that using `this("Alex", 22);`.

Answer (score 1):

Analogy from one newbie java coder to another:

You log into your Starbucks app, looking to place a *new* order of drinks. (1) If you tap “Buy with one click!” on the frappuccino image, it will create a *new* order that has a frappuccino in it, finalize the order, and place it all in one go. This is what your first two **Student** constructors do. (2) Or, you could just click the button, “Start a new order”, and you won’t have anything in your cart yet. The second option is what you have chosen to do in your code. Remember: “**new Student();**” is ONE new order because there is only ONE *new* keyword.

If you have ever tried to place an order, you know that you cannot place an order if the order contains nothing. So instead of immediately sending it to your Starbucks location, it gives you a chance to add items to your order. Everything that you want in your order goes in between the parentheses **()**.When you called “**this(“Alex”);**”, you were really filling your order with ONE “**Alex**” drink and then placing it because you closed the parentheses (told the app, “this is what is in my cart for my order”).

When you then called “**this(22)**”, your code got confused because you were trying to add a 22 drink to an order you already placed. You cannot order a drink and then, 5 minutes later, add another drink to the SAME order.

Suggestion: make a constructor **Student(name, age)** and call **this("Alex", 22)** instead.

Alternatively: call **this(22)** inside **Student(String)** instead!

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of using this keyword to call the current class constructor inside other  constructor.

you can call the current class constructor in first line of the constructor otherwise you get compile time error.

The reason if you create the object to call the constructor first check they any current class constructor is present or not if it present execute the constructor first and after that, this constructor is executed.

why we cannot use multiple this() in one constructor?. Because inside the constructor you can call one constructor at a time.